# Python list comprehension to calculate the set of categories for each row

Tags: python, pandas

My data = `data`

```
Model   A1BG    A1CF    A2M A2ML1   A3GALT2 A4GALT  foldchange
IM00499 N   L   L   G   N   N   0.285744
IM00499.1   L   N   D   G   D   D   0.005046
IM00980 N   N   N   N   N   N   -0.068949
IM01529 N   N   L   N   N   N   0.065914
IM01624 A   N   L   N   N   N   0.302100
IM01240 N   D   N   D   N   G   -0.428324
IM00807 N   L   A   N   D   N   0.257222
IM00999 N   N   N   N   N   D   0.056268
IM00983 N   N   N   N   N   N   0.107456
IM01076 N   N   D   A   N   N   0.218301
IM00803 N   D   N   N   N   D   -0.479368
IM00125 N   N   A   N   N   A   0.270428
IM00998 D   N   N   N   G   N   0.142748
IM00997 N   L   G   G   N   G   -0.154540
IM00996 N   L   N   N   N   L   -1.302023
```

The above data frame is divided into 5 categories = A, N, L, G and D

`feature = ['A1BG', 'A1CF', 'A2M', 'A2ML1', 'A3GALT2', 'A4GALT']`

Feature_level_partitions are arrays of combination of classification values

`feature_level_partitions = ['A', 'N' , 'L',  'G',  'D'], ['D'], ['L', 'G']`

I was using the below `list comprehension` to calculate `Hedge's G`.

```
        hedges_g = np.array(
            [
                Hedges_g(data[feature].isin(feature_level_partition), y)
                for feature_level_partition in feature_level_partitions
            ],
            dtype=np.float64,
        )
```

`Hedges_g` is defined as follows:

```
def Hedges_g(x, y):
    difference_of_means = abs(np.mean(y[x])[0] - np.mean(y[~x])[0])
    s_pooled_weighted = math.sqrt((((n1 - 1) * s1 ** 2) + ((n2 - 1) * s2 ** 2)) / (n1 + n2 - 2))
    return difference_of_means / s_pooled_weighted
```

I am interested in knowing how many models there are within each category. So for example if I divide up the data into ["D","L"] on one side, and the rest on the other, I want to know how many models have either "D" OR "L" and how many models have any of the other categories and then don't calculate `Hegde's G` if the number on either side is less than 2.

To answer the above query I tried the following code

```
[data[feature].isin(feature_level_partition).sum()
    for feature_level_partition in feature_level_partitions]
```

The above code gave me the number of models with the `feature_level_partitions`
However I also want to know the number of models without the `feature_level_partitions`

I also want to create a python function which calculates both above numbers in one line and fit this code as a `if statement` in my above `list comprehension` function

Comment: What you might think about @Megha is defining a new question in the context of both the comprehension and the models by defining a criteria for including 'foldchange' parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm not clear about is the definition of `y` - thats crucial to understanding what the code does. Just to note, although you've called the dataframe `data`, I've called it `df` (traditional shorthand). In terms of speed there will not be much in it between vectorised `pandas` and `numpy`. Explicitly using `iterrows` or else `apply` is when it slows down a lot.

Possibilities of the definition of `y`.

1.

```
y = df.drop(['Model', 'foldchange'], axis=1)
```

I think the above is more likely, or ...

2.

```
y = df['fold change']
```

What I think is occurring is `np.mean` is performing a boolean operation on the feature columns. What I didn't understand though was this ...

```
abs(np.mean(y[x])[0] - np.mean(y[~x])[0])
```

.. this is because for example model 'IM00980' albeit the mean is 0 this will always be 1 under the above equation. This is because `y[~x]` will be 1 for all values and thus abs(0 - 1) is 1. Equally if all columns in a row were 1 the output would also be 1 because abs(1-0) is 1. Anyway, what I would do is explicitly perform the operation within `pandas` rather than coercing `np` into a boolean operation. This is

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'/pathtofile/megha.csv', delimiter="\t")

feature = ['A1BG', 'A1CF', 'A2M', 'A2ML1', 'A3GALT2', 'A4GALT']
df=df.drop(['foldchange'],axis=1)
feature_level_partitions = ['L', 'G']
filtered = df[feature].isin(feature_level_partitions).eq(True).mul(1)
df2 = df['Model'].to_frame().join(filtered)
df2['mean'] = df2[feature].mean(axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Here ~x would simply `1 - mean` as a new pandas column, i.e. `df2['~mean'] = df2['mean'] - 1`

The output of that code is:

| - | Model | A1BG | A1CF | A2M | A2ML1 | A3GALT2 | A4GALT | mean. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | IM00499 | 0 | 1. | 1. | 1. | 0. | 0. | 0.500000 |
| 1 | IM00499.1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.333333 |
| 2 | IM00980 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 3 | IM01529 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.166667 |
| 4 | IM01624 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.166667 |
| 5 | IM01240 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.166667 |
| 6 | IM00807 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.166667 |
| 7 | IM00999 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 8 | IM00983 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 9 | IM01076 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 10 | IM00803 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 11 | IM00125 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.000000 |
| 12 | IM00998 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.166667 |
| 13 | IM00997 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0.666667 |
| 14 | IM00996 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.333333 |

---

If this is correct it provides the basis to move forward for all other operations. Basically, what I'm saying is I think is good to break open the `numpy` into explicit `pandas` operations, what is happening is there's a mix of `pandas` and `numpy` and I would recommend going down one route or the other.